# Coloring of a referenced cell (Excel, VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a column of referenced numbers and I would like to color the referenced cell automatically after right clicking, how can I refer to the reference cell in VBA. In the exmaple I have the referenced values in column [O]. At [O4] I have the value [=$G$12]. If I click on [O4] I want to color it together with the reference cell G12. It would be an additional step that I would like to color the cell above [G12] as well.
I tried to insert this in the formula:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($O$4),"$",""),1,1,"")
```

Which would give back the reference cell [G12] in a normal excel sheet without equal sign but the script doesn't work with it.

Thank you for the support in advance!

```
Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$O$4" '<~ if cell A1 is clicked, highlight cells C5-C9 yellow
          Cancel = True
          If .Range("O4,G11:G12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
             .Range("O4,G11:G12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
             .Range("O4,G11:G12").Font.Bold = False
        Else: .Range("O4,G11:G12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
              .Range("O4,G11:G12").Font.Bold = True
          End If
End Select
```

Comment: Are your formulas all of the sort "=A1" or are they more complicated?

Comment: A1 in the comment is old but I got the solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [`Precedents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents) property of `Range` obejct:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$O$4"
            Cancel = True

            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Target.Precedents
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Target
            Else
                Set rng = Union(Target, rng, rng.Offset(-1))
            End If
            If rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                rng.Font.Bold = False
            Else
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
                rng.Font.Bold = True
            End If

    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, please:

```
Dim strForm As String, newRng As Range
 Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$O$4" '<~ if cell A1 is clicked, highlight cells C5-C9 yellow
          Cancel = True
          strForm = Target.Formula
          'split string formula on "$" character and use the array obtained elements, to build the new address
          Set newRng = Range(Range(Split(strForm, "$")(1) & Split(strForm, "$")(2) - 1).Address & ":" & _
                                            Range(Split(strForm, "$")(1) & Split(strForm, "$")(2)).Address)
          If Range(Target.Address(0, 0) & "," & newRng.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then
             Range(Target.Address(0, 0) & "," & newRng.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
             Range(Target.Address(0, 0) & "," & newRng.Address).Font.Bold = False
        Else: Range(Target.Address(0, 0) & "," & newRng.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
              Range(Target.Address(0, 0) & "," & newRng.Address).Font.Bold = True
          End If
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for both of you. Finaly it works. I have an additonal qiestion in order to reduce the length of the code.

Lets consider it as a block for coloring cells if I clcik on [O4] cell. If I dont want to repeate this block many times but I want the same feature for the range of [O4:O45] with corresponding refernce content how I can do that? Sorry I'm not so experenced in coding but I'm very satisfied wth the result so far. 
Thanks a lot!